# Spring MVC - Error code 406 with specific url parameter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

I develop a Spring MVC application with a REST API.

I have this method in a controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/roomId/{roomId}",produces = "application/json")
public List<DayStatisticDto> findBySiteAndRoom(@PathVariable("roomId") String roomId, @RequestParam("timestamp") String timestamp, @RequestParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize) throws ParseException {
    List<DayStatisticDto> dayStatisticDtos = dayStatisticService.latestDailyStatisticsForRoom(getCurrentUserSiteCode(), roomId, pageSize, timestamp, false);
    return dayStatisticDtos;
}
```

**When I make this get request** :

http://localhost:8080/api/activities/roomId/I1.A.122?timestamp=2016-11-11T12:02:34.421+0100&pageSize=10

With this request parameters :

- Accept:application/json
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
- Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
- Cache-Control:no-cache
- Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.486025197.1475764350;JSESSIONID=6716A5824088BC0F46A6B74D5FB25A3E
- Host:localhost:8080
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36

I get a correct JSON object as response.

**But when I change the parameter "roomId" from I1.A.122 to I1.A.123 :**

http://localhost:8080/api/activities/roomId/I1.A.123?timestamp=2016-11-11T12:02:34.421+0100&pageSize=10

With this request parameters :

- Accept:application/json
- Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
- Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
- Cache-Control:no-cache
- Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.486025197.1475764350; JSESSIONID=6716A5824088BC0F46A6B74D5FB25A3E
- Host:localhost:8080
- User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36

I receive a error code **406 - Inacceptable**

I use this kind of request everywhere in the projet and I never had this kind of issue. The parameter "roomId" still a normal integer value. How can it generate issue with Spring Mvc ? The headers and the running code still exactly the same.

When I put a breakpoint at the first line of the "findBySiteAndRoom" method, in the first case it reaches the point. But in the second case, it returns the 406 error code before reaching the break point.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When I pass the room ID in requestparam rather than in pathvariable, it's working with the roomId I1.A.123 : http://localhost:8080/api/activities/room?roomId=I1.A.123&timestamp=2016-11-11T12:02:34.421+0100&pageSize=1

When I add an extra word after the roomId, it's working with the room Id I1.A.213 : http://localhost:8080/api/activities/room/I1.A.123/test?timestamp=2016-11-11T12:02:34.421+0100&pageSize=1 

How can we explain that ? Is it a bug in Spring MVC ?

Comment: When I add a "/" just after the roomId value, it's working too : http://localhost:8080/api/activities/roomId/I1.A.123/?timestamp=2016-11-11T12:02:34.421+0100&pageSize=10

Comment: your path mapping goes @RequestMapping(value="/roomId/{roomId}",produces = "application/json")
or 
@RequestMapping(value="/room/{roomId}",produces = "application/json") ? (roomId vs room  )

Comment: The path mapping is @RequestMapping(value="/roomId/{roomId}",produces = "application/json")

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of fix. I created a Spring config that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and I overrode the "configureContentNegotiation" method like this :

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
}
```

With this parameter, it works perfectly.

But I still don't understand what can explain that with a room ID I1.A.122 it works and with room ID I1.A.123 it doesn't work.